# How to detect Bluetooth, without rebooting

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

I have an external bluetooth adapter, it works if I attach it before booting, but if I connect it afterwards it fails to detect any device.

Is there any command to scan for and detect devices?

Comment: how do you connect this device ? via usb ? in other words, is this a usb bluetooth adapter that doesn't get enabled if you plugin after booting ?

Comment: its via usb, thats right @kaushik

Comment: [`hcitool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/hcitool.1.html) and [`sdptool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/sdptool.1.html) may help.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try restarting the init.d service?

```
:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

Executing this command after you connect your usb bluetooth adapter should restart the service and make the bluetooth service recognize new connections/adapters/etc....

Let me know...

Answer (score 5):

You should check to see if the USB bluetooth kernel module (driver) is loaded.

```
lsmod | grep btusb
```

If it doesn't return anything, then you need to load the kernel module with:

```
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: Note: This works on an unmodified Ubuntu system with no extra packages installed. Great!

Comment: Even _if_ the driver is loaded and listed with the above `lsmod | grep btusb`, sometimes it helps to force a restart of it: `rmmod btusb`, then `modprobe btusb`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer `lsmod` to check for the bluetooth kernel module, you can also use `rfkill` to check the status of (and block and unblock) different wireless devices on your machine.

---

#### RFKILL

`rfkill` was merged into the linux kernel in 2.6 and is a simple way to manage wireless devices.

- [rfkill man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rfkill)
- [kernel.org docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rfkill.txt)

For example, view wireless devices by calling `rfkill` with no arguments:

```bsh
cat@rt~ $ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0     blocked unblocked
```

And get a little more details with `rfkill list $TYPE`:

```bsh
cat@rt~ $ rfkill list bluetooth
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Then (with sudo/root) you can block or unblock the devices with `rfkill block $TYPE` (or `$ID`):

```bsh
cat@rt~ $ sudo rfkill block bluetooth
cat@rt~ $ sudo rfkill block wlan
```

Now check their new status with `rfkill` again:

```bsh
cat@rt~ $ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE    SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   blocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0   blocked unblocked
```

Note the devices I disabled are listed `blocked` under `SOFT` but not `HARD`. This means we've disabled the device through software (and can re-enable the device through software).

A `HARD` blocked device indicates the wireless device was hardware blocked. This could be a hardware kill switch (some laptops have a switch to toggle wireless off), or the device may be disabled by bios, or possibly doesn't have a driver for the software to interact with it (double-check me on that last one though).

And to unblock a `SOFT` blocked device:

```bsh
cat@rt~ $ sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
cat@rt~ $ sudo rfkill unblock wlan
```